# I want to show led on / off on my webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, raspberry-pi

I am using `Raspberry pi` to automate a building. I just want to show led **on / off** on web page. If it gets 1 "led show zero status on 1  " or 0 "led show high status on 0  " from mysql database.

Here is my code. I want to replace Grey led png with Red led png file, I have stored value in JavaScript variable. but I think something is wrong with my javascript function or `if-else` statement .

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = '******'; // Password
$db_name = '*******'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = 'SELECT dev1 FROM `76Hlog` ORDER BY `Serial` DESC LIMIT 1';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>


<html>
<body>

<?php


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {

            $s1 = $row['dev1'];
                        echo $s1;                  

        }?>


<img id="myImage" src="/image-folder/ioff.png" width="50" height="50">



<script>



var val = <?php echo $s1; ?>;



function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (val == "1") {
        image.src = "/image-folder/ioff.png";
    } else if (val == "0") {
        image.src = "/image-folder/ion.png";
    }
}
</script>


<h1>the value for number is:  
 <script>
        document.write(val)
      </script></h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok though I'm not sure why you have this line
`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))`
Why would you need this in a while loop?

Also note that this will run once and if you expect the image to be replaced automatically this is not what will happen, for that to happen without a page refresh you will need to create an AJAX request.

Comment: i will edit while loop later, but my main focus is that i am unable to load image file after refreshing page

Comment: it only show "ioff.png" , and not change to "ion.png" if i get 0 value in var val

Comment: Are there any errors prior to trying to set "ion.png"? If it is unable to retrieve the first image for example it might make the whole page get stuck.

Comment: i am getting ioff.png on my page

Comment: changeImage is never called

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding quotation marks to the value returned by php?

```
var val = "<?php echo $s1; ?>";
```

Comment: i am able to store value in val variable and i checked it with document.write(val)

Answer (score 0):

To determine just call the javascript function on body load.
When it loads the php will run and when body has finished loading it will set the required image.

```
<body onload="changeImage()">
```

Now finally change the function so that php fetches the rows and saves it inside a variable when changeImage() is called.

```
function changeImage() {

  //Php code for connecting to database and saving the result in $s1

    var val = <?php echo $s1; ?>;
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (val == "1") {
        image.src = "/image-folder/ioff.png";
    } else if (val == "0") {
        image.src = "/image-folder/ion.png";
    }
}
```

If you want you can call this function after a specific interval too using

```
setInterval(changeImage, time_in_milliseconds);
```

Comment: Hi, bundle of thanks for this addition , i forgot to call the function , now it's working